# There is insufficient memory. Windows cannot load requested font

Tags: microsoft-word, memory, fonts

Word 365.

(I know there is another forum, but there is no conclusive answer.)

This error is only happening for **one specific word document that I have**. The font that couldn't be loaded is **Latin Modern, a font which I installed from the internet**.

This error doesn't occur, and the font works for **other word documents, even new ones I create**, but it just doesn't load for this specific document. (which is my resume, and I rather not have to re-create it).

I have tried making a copy-paste of that word document, but font still doesn't load.

**UPDATE**

So there are two types of files:

(1) those that are "infected" with this error (i.e. my resume.docx). When I open this file, the font can't load.
(2) those that are fine, and doesn't have this error. (Basically, everything except for my resume.docx, and all new files I create.

Now here's the interesting thing:

If I **first open a good file**, THEN open my resume.docx, then the font DOES LOAD.

If I **open my resume.docx first**, then open any other file, the font DOESN'T LOAD FOR ANY FILE.

So it feels as if there's something in my resume.docx that infects all other files when it is currently opened.

Comment: If you asked elsewhere, you should give a link to that so that we don't duplicate the effort. Maybe there is corrupted metadata in the document: [Remove hidden data and personal information by inspecting documents](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/remove-hidden-data-and-personal-information-by-inspecting-documents-356b7b5d-77af-44fe-a07f-9aa4d085966f).

Answer (score 1):

**Another option:**

Word has an Open and Repair option that you should use:

[image]

Open Word directly (do not just double-click on the offending file in the File Explorer), then navigate to the Open dialog and find and select the file, and then expand the menu on the Open button and select Open and Repair.

However, the sorts of issues I've experienced with Word document corruption have not typically been resolved this way, and I have to use the copy-paste method.

**OP states this is last ditch:**
When you copy-paste, paste without formatting (or paste as plain text).

Regular copy-paste in Word includes formatting data and likely copies the very corruption you need to clear out. Pasting as plain text will paste only the text, which is unlikely to contain the corruption.

Further, pasting without formatting doesn't always work, and in these cases you must paste into a Text Editor (Notepad, NOT a rich-text editor such as Wordpad) and then copy-paste back into Work to strip out everything.

Comment: And then you should be able to apply the font.

Comment: Ah, got it. This will be the last resort solution, since I end up copy-pasting everything and having to reformat. But nonetheless greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some other Word styles are applied in Resume template. You can try:

Select the text which you want to change the font, go to **Home** tab, in the **Styles** group, drag the drop-down window of listed styles, click **Clear Formatting**. Then apply Latin Modern font to have a try.